# How can I read Arabic characters in a filename with FileUtils.listFiles in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, arabic, fileutils

This is a method that returns a String array with all my files name in a specific folder. It works perfectly but doesn't work when reading a file with Arabic characters in it's filename. Any help is appreciated.

```
String[] name = new String[10];
        String[] finalName = new String[10];
        int i=0;
        File file = new File("/Users/Rakuten/Desktop/Trial");       
        Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(file, null, true);  
        for(File file2 : files){
            name[i]=file2.getName();
            finalName[i]=name[i].replace(".ppt","");
            i++;

        }

        return finalName;
```

Comment: What does 'doesn't work' mean? What happens? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I am getting the following error "Illegal character in path" and "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"

Comment: What does the Stack Trace for the exception say - where exactly is the error occurring?

Comment: Which version of Java is this, and what locale is it set to?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid target - java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 31: /Users/Rakuten/Desktop/Trial/ كنزي .ppt
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.addExternalRelationship(PackagePart.java:185)
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.addExternalRelationship(PackagePart.java:148)
 at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFHyperlink.setAddress(XSLFHyperlink.java:45)
 at Main.main(Main.java:91)

I am using an API called POI Apache.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem by duplicating the file in question and changing it's name to Latin-alphabet. Trivial solution because I don't really need the file afterwards, I just need the name of the file written on a PowerPoint and linked to it. And I would have stored this name before I rename the file.